# How to build a JS interface for an API

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm building an API interface in JS ES6 to allow me to use the CRUD rule in a better way and more efficient. My issue I'm not finding a way to make it work. 
I created my interface to accept some params and based on which method like GET or POST something should happen and I should see a specific result of the request.

I created an external `getProducts()` function but is ignored by the system I don't have errors and nothing happen is dead.

What I did in my fetch data interface as follow:

```
const api = "https://api";

const username = "username";
const password = "password";

const token = btoa(username + ":" + password);

window.request = async (url, params, method = "GET") => {
    const options = {
        method,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Basic " + token
        }
    };

    if (params) {
        if (method === "GET") {
            url += "?" + objectToQueryString(params);
        } else {
            options.body = JSON.stringify(params);
        }
    }

    const response = await fetch(api + url, options);

    if (response.status !== 200) {
        return generateErrorResponse(
            "The server responded with an unexpected status."
        );
    }

    const result = await response.json();

    return result;
};

objectToQueryString = obj => {
    return Object.keys(obj)
        .map(key => key + "=" + obj[key])
        .join("&");
};

generateErrorResponse = message => {
    return {
        status: "error",
        message
    };
};

const Fetch  = () => {

    get = (url, params) => {
        return request(url, params);
    };

    create = (url, params) => {
        return request(url, params, "POST");
    };

    update = (url, params) => {
        return request(url, params, "PUT");
    };

    remove = (url, params) => {
        return request(url, params, "DELETE");
    };
};
```

And the function which should get the data:

```
getProducts = async () => {
    const products = await Fetch.get("/product");
};
```

I have trouble understanding what wrong and what should I do to make it run.

Comment: Why would `Fetch` be a function? Use an object literal instead, and use [method notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions), i.e. `const Fetch = { get(url, params){` … `}, create(url, params){` … `},` … `};`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon could you please show an example as you showed is not doing anything as was before.

Comment: The methods may have to be `async`, i.e. `async get` etc.

Comment: The getProducts function doesn't return the products ...

Comment: Also with a return not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt using a fake endpoint and everything is working properly

```js
const api = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com";

const username = "username";
const password = "password";

const token = btoa(username + ":" + password);

window.request = async (url, params, method = "GET") => {
    const options = {
        method,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Basic " + token
        }
    };

    if (params) {
        if (method === "GET") {
            url += "?" + objectToQueryString(params);
        } else {
            options.body = JSON.stringify(params);
        }
    }

    const response = await fetch(api + url, options);

    if (response.status !== 200) {
        return generateErrorResponse(
            "The server responded with an unexpected status."
        );
    }

    const result = await response.json();

    return result;
};

objectToQueryString = obj => {
    return Object.keys(obj)
        .map(key => key + "=" + obj[key])
        .join("&");
};

generateErrorResponse = message => {
    return {
        status: "error",
        message
    };
};

const Fetch = {
    get: (url, params) => request(url, params),
    create: (url, params) => request(url, params, "POST"),
    update: (url, params) => request(url, params, "PUT"),
    remove: (url, params) => request(url, params, "DELETE")
};

const getProducts = async () => {
    const products = await Fetch.get("/posts");
    console.log(products);
};

getProducts();
```

First I changed `Fetch` to an object with methods instead of a function returning other functions:

```js
const Fetch = {
    get: (url, params) => request(url, params),
    create: (url, params) => request(url, params, "POST"),
    update: (url, params) => request(url, params, "PUT"),
    remove: (url, params) => request(url, params, "DELETE")
};
```

I did not make these functions async as someone else mentioned because they do not need to be.  the `request` function already returns a promise because it is an async function so the `Fetch` function will return a promise as well.

Next I made get products a `const` as it was not previously defined.

```
const getProducts = async () => {
    const products = await Fetch.get("/posts");
    console.log(products);
};
```

I also changed its URL to posts to match the fake endpoint so don't get tripped up by that if you copy and paste.

Finally, I added a `console.log()` to the get products function.  I'm not sure how you are capturing the `products` value but by default the `getProducts` function returns a promise so it must be handled asynchronously.

Also I'm not sure about your api url `const api = "https://api";` but thats probably not going to return you anything haha.

Here's a JSBin if you want to look at my version more closely: https://jsbin.com/jokayikaro/edit?js,console

Comment: Yes, that interesting but no data still is fetched no errors are shown at all :(

Comment: I need to show some products and to have do I need on window load to load my get or can I make an init function for it? what could be the best to do it?

Comment: You can make an init function if you want, or just call the `getProducts` function after defining everything else.  Either way you'd need to invoke the function with `init()` or `getProducts()`  If you still aren't getting data or an error that's probably because your `getProducts` function is never being called